# How to convert Kivy touch corordinates to widget space

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

i have a simple `ModalView` and its `size` is `(640,426)`.My window's size is `(1366,732)`.My Screen Resolution is `(1366,768)`.When i click at the top left corner of the `ModalView`,i get something like `363,690`.Which is my touch coordinates taken from the window itself.i would however like to somehow convert this value to local widget space so that touching the top left corner i get the coordinate `(0,0)` instead of `(363,690)`.Is this possible with kivy or any other way.What Im trying to do,for those interested is to crop an image using a box drawn by the user.Drawing the box isn't the problem,the problem is getting those bounds and transfering them to the image's coords.

NB: I read about the `to_local(),to_parent(),to_window()` and those functions are simply not working...for some reason,maybe i missed a thing there,would appreciate your help big time

Here is the code similar to my usecase but stripped

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CropBounds(ModalView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CropBounds, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.to_crop = True
        self.size = (400,400)
        print('Center: ',self.center)
        print('Size: ',self.size)
        print('Window Center: ',Window.center)
        print('Window Size:(',Window.width,',',Window.height,')')

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.canvas.clear()

        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.to_crop:
            with self.canvas:

                    self.start_x = touch.x
                    self.start_y = touch.y
                    touch.ud['area'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y, touch.x, 400,touch.x, touch.y,touch.x, touch.y, touch.x, touch.y))
                    print("Pos: ",touch.pos)
                    print(touch.x,touch.y)
        return True
    return MainWindow().on_touch_down(touch)

class GalleryWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GalleryWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(Button(text='crop',size_hint=(1,None),size=(None,40),on_release=self.crop_img))
    def crop_img(self):
        bounds = CropBounds()
        bounds.open()

class GalleryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GalleryWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    GalleryApp().run()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary, because your question is: I have tried this and it does not work for me, and in those cases you must provide an MCVE, provide it or not depends on you, since as you have tried something I think it will not be difficult to show it. :-)

Comment: Alright,updating question now..its just tat I might have to paste all the code in,which might be too long..let me try though

Comment: I think you already have enough reputation to know that an MCVE is not about copying your project but to create a small example that has everything you need to run and reflects your problem, if you do not know read the link please.

Comment: Yup,that i do..anyway,i have updated a minimal example to my question,do you need more?

Comment: Your post is still not an MCV example (try running it). Anyway, all the coordinate conversion methods that you mention have no effect unless you are using a `RelativeLayout` (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#coordinate-systems)). So, to get the touch coordinates relative to your `ModalView`, just subtract the position of the `ModalView` from the touch coordinates.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, added the code...I have to say though that what you said about subtracting the ModalView pos from the touch coordinates simply didn't work..any more thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the `ModalView` position from the `touch` coordinates does work. I think your are getting confused about the size and position of your `ModalView`. The way your code is written, the `ModalView` is the same size and position as your `GalleryWindow` (recall that the default `size_hint` is (1.0, 1.0)). So, for there to be any difference between coordinates in the `ModalView` and `GalleryWindow`, you need to change the `size_hint` for the `ModalView`.

After correcting many errors in your code (to get it to run). I have made some changes to demonstrate the position of the `ModalView` and the location of the touch.

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CropBounds(ModalView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CropBounds, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.to_crop = True
        self.size_hint = (None, None)  # without this, the size below has no effect
        self.size = (400,400)
        print('Center: ',self.center)
        print('Size: ',self.size)
        print('Window Center: ',Window.center)
        print('Window Size:(',Window.width,',',Window.height,')')

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.to_crop:
            self.canvas.clear()
            with self.canvas:
                # plot the boundary of the ModalView
                Line(points=[self.pos[0], self.pos[1],
                                        self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.height,
                                        self.pos[0] + self.width, self.pos[1] + self.height,
                                        self.pos[0] + self.width, self.pos[1],
                                        self.pos[0], self.pos[1]])
                # plot a line from the touch point to the pos of the ModalView
                Line(points=[self.pos[0], self.pos[1], touch.x, touch.y])

            # calculate touch minus position of ModalView
            touch_in_modal = (touch.x - self.pos[0], touch.y - self.pos[1])
            print('touch : ' + str(touch.pos) + ', touch in modal: ' + str(touch_in_modal))
            return True
        #return MainWindow().on_touch_down(touch)

class GalleryWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GalleryWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='crop',size_hint=(1,None),size=(40,40),on_release=self.crop_img))
    def crop_img(self, *args):
        bounds = CropBounds()
        bounds.open()


class GalleryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GalleryWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    GalleryApp().run()
```

If you want to see what was happening in your code, just comment out the `size_hint` line.

Also, when we ask you to post a MCV example, please try running what you post. If we have to debug your example before we can see what you problem is, you won't get many responses.